# C# have nullable object of same type in constructor

Tags: c#, nullable

Below is my code:

```
class Phrase
{
    public String Name { get; private set; }
    public Head Head { get; private set; }
    public Phrase? Complement { get; private set; }

    public Phrase(String Name, Head Head, Phrase? Complement)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Head = Head;
        this.Complement = Complement;
    }

}
```

This is causing a compile-time error stating

> "The type 'Phrase' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use
>   it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable"

What I'm **trying** to do is have a nullable class variable `Complement`, and allow it to be set in the constructor. How do I best do this?

Comment: we need to see the definition of the type Phrase

Comment: If `Phrase` is a `class` then it can _already_ be null, so a nullable `Phrase` is pointkess.  `Nullable` only applies to value types (structs) that cannot be bull intrinsically.

Comment: @DStanley more than simply pointless, `Nullable<T>` has a restriction on the generic type parameter `T` which *limits* it to value types, hence the error.

Comment: The error message is telling you what's wrong, your trying to apply nullable (?) to a nullable reference type (i.e. it's not a non-nullable value type)

Comment: simply put `if (Complement == null)`

Comment: The code I posted is the definition of the type Phrase. Sorry about the ambiguity

Comment: Your code example is missing something, can you copy/paste the **exact** code you have, because what you've posted has nothing that uses `Nullable<T>` or `TypeName?` in it...

Comment: The issue was I assumed that reference types cannot be null without the `?` syntax. I removed the question marks, and everything is now working great. Thanks for the help and sorry for the confusion!

Comment: It's the other way around, value types cannot be null without the ?. reference types can always be nulled.

Comment: Yeah sorry haha that's what I meant! Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the error, `Phrase` is already a nullable type.  This is because it's a class:

```
class Phrase
{
    // ...
}
```

Classes, being reference types, are always nullable.  In order to use `Nullable<T>` (and the `?` shorthand syntax thereof), the type must be non-nullable.  Which would be a primitive type or a `struct`:

```
struct Phrase
{
    // ...
}
```

Note that there are *considerable* differences between classes and structs aside from simply whether or not they're nullable.  If you want to make your type a `struct`, that could easily be a very significant change to your code.  If, on the other hand, you simply want to allow `null` in that constructor then it does that by default, simply remove the `?` constructs.

Answer (score -3):

```
public String Name { get; private set; }
public Head Head { get; private set; }
public Phrase? Complement { get; private set; }

public Phrase(String Name, Head Head, Phrase? Complement)
{
    this.Name = Name;
    this.Head = Head;
    this.Complement = Complement;
}
```

this.Complement  is already nullable, you can't put the "Value" property of the Complement parameter, plus if Phrase is a Class it shouldn't be nullable (because it's already is)

Comment: No, I can put `Value` wherever I want: `int? x = 42; int? y = x.Value;` works just fine...